# Why can ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')) in telebot happen?

Tags: proxy, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I wrote telegram bot and ran it on google engine in the American zone (Telegram is blocked in my country). Most of the time, everything works fine, but sometimes the bot starts to throw an error

> ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError (104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

He gives this error 2 times (on two messages), and the third time he answers well. On the Internet, the answer to this problem is usually a proxy problem. I do not use proxy. Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Are there any methods to solve it?

Code is pretty simple:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['check'])
def send_text(message):
    try:
        # Here bot connects to my db and gets info from it
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'some message')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("Problem in check function: ", message.chat.id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        try:
            bot.polling(none_stop=True, timeout=30)
        except:
            time.sleep(15)
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is raised since the connection to the server is open for too long, so it gets denied.  Set this parameter in your bot initialization to reset the connection every 5 minutes:

```
apihelper.SESSION_TIME_TO_LIVE = 60 * 5
```